# MYSQL function MAX() between 5 databases

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, union, sql-limit

I work in the PHPMYADMIN environment. My goal was to download data from the Internet, which describe judges, the regions where they work, the files they made, the number of decisions, their salaries and similar things I upload in my databases. I have created 5 databases, each of which symbolizes a specific region (part of the country). Now my goal is, for example, to find the judge with the highest number of decisions. Using this command:

```
SELECT ID_sudca
     , Rozhodnutia
  FROM sudy_sk.informacie
UNION 
SELECT id_sudcu
     , rozhodnutie
  FROM nabozny1.sudca
UNION  
SELECT SUDCA_ID
     , POCET_ROZHODNUTI
  FROM `ke-sud-neznik`.`sudca`
UNION  SELECT `ID_sudca`, `Rozhodnutia` 
  FROM `gerboc`.`sudcovia` 
UNION 
SELECT `ID_SUDCU`, `Rozhodnutia` 
   FROM `biz`.`sudcovia`;`
```

I will create a lookup table in which all judges are loaded under judge_id (it is a unique number that symbolizes each judge) and the number of decisions, that is, as if I put all the judges and their numbers in this lookup table, which is symbolized by . My goal now is to find out all the information from all the regions (5 databases) and for example I will think about the first question and that is, the judge with the highest / lowest number of decisions. I want to use the MAX () function, but it is necessary (at least I think so) to use it in a pile with the mentioned display. But unfortunately I can't do it. Can't you help me? Or any idea?

Using your first display, it will show me some output, but this output is not correct. The order of the values ​​is not as correct as you can see.

```
    select id_sudca, rozhodnutia from sudy_sk.informacie 
union select id_sudcu, rozhodnutie from nabozny1.sudca 
union select sudca_id, pocet_rozhodnuti from `ke-sud-neznik`.sudca
union select id_sudca, rozhodnutia from gerboc.sudcovia 
union select id_sudcu, rozhodnutia from biz.sudcovia
order by rozhodnutia;
```

[image]

Interestingly, I tried the same view just changed the names of the tables to find out who has the highest salary of judges for 2018 (order by desc) and here it was rightly shown to me, but when I found the number of hearings no longer, and I think about that from why is that so. Any idea ?

```
select id_sudca, plat_2018 from sudy_sk.enrichment_platy union select id_sudcu, prijem_2018 from nabozny1.m_priznania union select id_priznania, prijmy_za_rok_2018 from putrovec.majetkove_priznania order by plat_2018;
```

[image]

I already know where the error was, this condition for select union was not met:

The columns must also have similar data types

Comment: "I have created 5 databases" - why? And even if there was a good reason, wouldn't it have been more sensible to use the same structure? You can't find "ALL" the information using an aggregate function.

Comment: what structure do you mean?

Comment: Including mathematical operators in table/column identifiers is a cataclysmically bad idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just `order by` and `limit`:

```
select id_sudca, rozhodnutia from sudy_sk.informacie 
union select id_sudcu, rozhodnutie from nabozny1.sudca 
union select sudca_id, pocet_rozhodnuti from `ke-sud-neznik`.sudca
union select id_sudca, rozhodnutia from gerboc.sudcovia 
union select id_sudcu, rozhodnutia from biz.sudcovia
order by rozhodnutia desc limit 1
```

Or, if the same `id_suca` may appear in different tables, use aggregation

```
select id_sudca, sum(rozhodnutia) 
from (
    select id_sudca, rozhodnutia from sudy_sk.informacie 
    union select id_sudcu, rozhodnutie from nabozny1.sudca 
    union  select sudca_id, pocet_rozhodnuti from ke-sud-neznik.sudca
    union  select id_sudca, rozhodnutia from gerboc.sudcovia 
    union  select id_sudcu, rozhodnutia from biz.sudcovia
) t
group by id_sudca
order by sum(rozhodnutia) desc limit 1
```

Comment: I still want to ask, I have created connections of primary and foreign keys between the tables, and when I use your command I will of course list the output I wanted, but when I click on judge_id (to see what the name is hidden under this number) does not fit me to tables of judges with names ... would it be nice to insert an inner join display into this command? or?

Comment: @JozefVendel: that sounds like a different question than the one you originally asked, that did not mention these concerns. If so, it should be asked as *a new question*.

Comment: Yes, I will probably put it as a new question, but I'm still solving this question and I'm looking for why the output is wrong, as you can see below, I also attached a picture.

Comment: @JozefVendel: I can see that you posted another question, which is the right way to go in my opinion. Meanwhile, is there a reason why you unaccepted this answer?

Comment: As you can see in the picture it doesn't sort me the correct values ​​for the decision field and I think about why

Comment: I already know where the error was, this condition for select union was not met:

The columns must also have similar data types